# The localhost still keep working after stop Python SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: simplehttpserver

I am always working in the Windows for web app development, and sometimes I need to setup a simple Web Server, and I always use the Python SimpleHTTPServer method, which is nice.
`python -m SimpleHTTPServer` 
and of course, the default port is 8000. 
But I find one problem that, sometimes when I cancel or stop the SimpleHTTPServer, the `localhost:8000` is still working, and the page stilled can be loaded.
So what the reason for this issue? How can I clean it.
Regards

Edit
Find one solution to remove from DevTool of Chrome Browser. Need some simple setting

Comment: how are you stopping your server ?

Comment: In cmd just ctrl c... Am I wrong, if so what's the correct way to do this? Thank you

Comment: interesting... had the same issue. apparently chrome was caching it...